# Localhost ports no longer work for any NextJS app

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, localhost

### Edit

Was able to produce an error. It's not much but its something. It's from Clerk, an auth service:

```
Failed to proxy https://api.clerk.dev/v1/public/interstitial?clerk_js_version=latest&publishable_key=pk_test_dml0YWwtYmVkYnVnLTI4L Error [ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT]: Socket connection timeout
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1098:20)
    at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1637:3)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
  code: 'ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'
}
error - Error [ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT]: Socket connection timeout
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1098:20)
    at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1637:3)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
  code: 'ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'
}
```

Also: just realized this might be an internet issue, but a confusing one at that. on my work Mac (2021 M1 pro) I also cannot npm install with any success. It just hangs. Since its the same problem then must be internet. However, I am currently getting 450mbps/32mbps upload/download and my internet in all other respects works fine. I can watch youtube, stream, etc.

Why would my terminal operations be stalling???

### Summary

I can't use my local host ports and I cant use npm. `npm install` never completed. Local host ports just show a page load forever. I can no longer run any of my NextJS apps on a localhost port without issues. The browser tab just spins forever or I get a TypeError from the undici/fetch method. Everything was working fine. The last thing I did before everything broke was I made some changes to a production app *that is deployed perfectly fine*, and I downloaded a VScode extension called Pretty Typescript Errors. I closed my laptop and bang. Nothing works.

I'm using:

```
MacOS Ventura 13.0

latest vscode

node: 19.0.0
nextjs: > 13.0.0 (different minor versions across projects)
```

### What I've tried

- Running this in a none vscode terminal
- Updating vscode (which required copying it to the applications folder as it was a read-only volume)
- Running other projects (they get different errors which I'll explain in a sec)
- Changing the localhost ports (8080, 5000, whatever random number)
- changing node versions using nvm

### Errors

- One case is that nothing happens at all. The localhost server just shows a loading spinner and doesn't do anything. It doesn't show connection errors from the server or websocket or anything
- Another case, for a specific project (that's also deployed on vercel), is that I am suddenly getting an error about undici/fetch having a TypeError and the connection timing out. The server starts and I can see my home page, but my queries run into this error. **This project is running perfect on vercel**.
- Also I can no longer `npm install` anything with success. I deleted the node_modules and package-lock for a project, and the npm install just... never finishes.

I can't even think of any code that would be helpful beyond the node version.

I'm at such a loss for words. I can't find anything that addresses a problem like this. Thank you. Please let me know if I can provide any info that might clear things up.

Comment: Did you find out what caused this issue? Seeing something similar